# Ember component computed function does not rerun when data changes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have stored a string value within a computed property like so:

```
clientId: Ember.computed.oneWay("_clientId")
```

where _clientId is defined as a property on the object like so:

```
export default Ember.service.extend { _clientId: null, clientId: Ember.computed.oneWay("_clientId"), updateId() {this.set("_clientId", "fe48822d-bf50-44a1-9ce0-61b06504d726"); } }
```

I then have a component with a computed property like so:

```
chartData: Ember.computed("data", function () {
    const data = this.get("data");

    const clientId = this.get("session").get("clientId");
    console.log(clientId);

    if (data && data.get("left") !== undefined && data.get("right") !== undefined) {
        return data;
    }

    this.set("_chartDisplayData", null);
    return null;
})
```

When I called updateId, i expected the chartData function to be re-run as the value of the clientId is changed (i verified that the value gets changed for clientId). However, the chartData function never re-runs, why is this?

Comment: You seem to be looking for an observer rather than a computed property. The computed property logic will not fire unless `chartData` is being referenced from somewhere, such as a template. In general, `set` inside a computed property definition is a code smell and probably means you aren't doing things right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the [computed property about *all* of your dependencies](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_multiple-dependents-on-the-same-object). First, the computed property will never run if it isn't being used somewhere. If you aren't using it you need an [observer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/object-model/observers/) instead. But assuming you are actually using it, the computed property will only recompute itself when one of the listed dependencies change. And if you list an object as a dependency, it will not update if only some of the object's properties are changed, only if the entire object is replaced. Try this:

```
chartData: Ember.computed("data.left", "data.right", "session.clientId", function () {
    const data = this.get("data");

    const clientId = this.get("session.clientId");
    console.log(clientId);

    if (data && data.get("left") !== undefined && data.get("right") !== undefined) {
        return data;
    }

    this.set("_chartDisplayData", null);
    return null;
})
```